# Optional value in array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, option-type

Can someone explain to me why this code here returns the error: 
"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

```
if let steps = legs[0]["steps"] {
    for i in 0...steps.length {
        print(steps[i])
    }
}
```

while this code:

```
let steps = legs[0]["steps"]!
print(steps[0])
```

returns the desired output? I am very confused as I have not been able to get all the values of steps contained in an array somehow..

Similarly:

```
for i in 0...legs[0]["steps"]!.length {
    print(legs[0]["steps"]![i]["start_location"])
}
```

gets fatal error while:

```
print(legs[0]["steps"]![0]["start_location"])
```

returns an optional value

Comment: You have to show us the original declaration of `legs` and any subtypes that that refers to.

Comment: Better use "for in" loops. See http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift/1186/loops/3839/for-in-loop

Comment: But he didn't get an Array out of bounds error. He got a nil Optional error

Comment: Am I missing something? The length of an array in Swift is `count`, not `length`.

Comment: @BaseZen lol as usual I'm cursing everything from the makers of swift to xcode and in the end it's me who is 100% a dummy. Thanks man, that was it. Too much python.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of what's inside legs and steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### length??

First of all what is the type of `steps`? If it's an array it does not have a `length` property but `count`.

### What is happening?

Lets take a look at this example snippet of code

```
let words = ["Hello", "world"]

for i in 0...words.count {
    print(words[i])
}
```

Here `words.count` is `2` so the `for` is being executed 3 times (i=0, i=1, i=2).
Since arrays indexes begin from `0`, the following elements are available

```
words[0] // "Hello"
words[1] // "world"
```

As you can imagine the last execution of the loop (when `i=2`) does access `words[2]` which does not exists! And this produces a crash.

### Accessing the right index

Now let's take a look at your `for loop`

```
for i in 0...steps.length {
    print(steps[i])
}
```

As described in the previous paragraph, over the last loop execution you are accessing an element that does not exists. It should be

```
for i in 0..<steps.count {
    print(steps[i])
}
```

### For in

Even better you could get rid of the indexes and simply write

```
for step in steps {
    print(step)
}
```

### For each

Another syntax, same result of the previous block of code

```
steps.forEach { step in
    print(step)
}
```

Comment: Yep, as you and BaseZen have pointed out to me it's not length lol it's count. I've been coding in python too much. Thanks!